# Making degree of every node 2 from 1 when node h is connected with every other nodes at min cost

Tags: graph-theory

There are n nodes in total (maximum value for n can be 2000) . Now node h is already connected to every other nodes already and we are given cost of connecting every pair of nodes in adjacency matrix . We need to make every node's degree atleast 2 (initially each nodes degree is 1 since it is connected with node h initially) in minimum cost .

*Note* :
(1) Degree of a node is nos. of edges connected to that node.
(2)h is always equal to 1 .

How can we do this ? I have a greedy algorithm that we sort pairs of costs between each 2 nodes & pick pairs with minimum cost such that all nodes attain degree 2 , but this will surely fail .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can ignore *h* and think of the problem as adding edges such that each vertex has degree at least 1. If the number of vertices is even, this is simply a [perfect matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_matching). Otherwise, it is a perfect matching plus one vertex connected to one other vertex (giving that vertex degree 2). You can solve those by simply trying all possibilities for the extra vertex, and solving *n* perfect matching problems.